# how to add a new customer in list in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm working this code for almost 10 hours but i can not find out where i'm doing wrong .If you could help me you are really making my day.The problem is that I'm trying to add a new customer and save it in my list but when i'm click in submit button .It does not work nothing is saving in my list and keeps looping my other customers .

```
private void Sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    customer newCus = new customer();
    account newAcc= new account();

    try
    {
        newCus.NAME = Nameadd.Text;
        newCus.pin = pinadd.Text;
        newAcc.PIN = pinadd.Text;
        newAcc.accountnumber = Accountnumadd.Text;
        newAcc.accounttype = 'C';
        for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
        {
            {
                if(newAcc.accounttype == 'C')
                {
                    newAcc.PIN = pinadd.Text;
                    newAcc.accountnumber = Accountnumadd.Text;
                    newAcc.accounttype = 'S';
                }
            }
            cuslist.add(newCus);
            acclist.add(newAcc);
            savefile();
            saveaccount();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}

//save to customer file
public void savefile()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("account.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cuslist.Count; i++)
        {
            var info = new List<string>
            {
                acclist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                acclist[i].PIN,
                acclist[i].accountnumber,
                acclist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
            };
            var account = String.Join(";", info);
            writer.WriteLine(account);
        }
    }
}

public void saveaccount()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("account.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
        {
            var info = new List<string>
            {
                acclist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                acclist[i].PIN,
                acclist[i].accountnumber,
                acclist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
            };
            var account = String.Join(";", info);
            writer.WriteLine(account);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to provide some more information. I see references to instances called `cuslist` and `acclist`, but do not see their definitions. We also need to see the relevant code in `savefile()` and `saveaccount()` otherwise we cannot tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Where is `cuslist` defined?  Does the same problem happen with `acclist`?  What do `savefile()` and `saveaccount()` do?  When you step through in a debugger, where specifically is the problem happening?

Comment: yes you are right Sorry for that
acclist = account list 
cuslist=customer List

Comment: for starters also learn how to properly format your code you do not need double `{ {` open braces for this line
`for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
        {
            {` also if you are adding / populating a list in a loop the List you need to add this line inside of the loop `customer newCus = new customer();` I would recommend creating a List<T> Class for both objects Customer and Account and figuring out if you want that Account List<T> List to be the parent with Child Customers as a ListT> within the Account class would be really nice to see what both classes look like too

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. You need to edit your question and provide the actual code containing the definitions of `cuslist`, `acclist`, `savefile()` and `saveaccount()` otherwise we can't help pinpoint where the problem is. It is likely in one or both of those two functions as both `acclist` and `cuslist` appear to be standard collections.

Comment: @gmiley just added them now

Comment: @lediya: So where do you ever save `cuslist`?

Comment: @David yes bro where is says savefile

Comment: You are saving `acclist` twice. Both functions are doing the exact same thing.

Comment: @lediya: You're saving the data from `acclist`, not `cuslist`.  And then you immediately overwrite the file when you call `saveaccount()`.

Comment: @gmiley where my friend ?

Comment: @lediya: In *the code you wrote*.  *Look* at your code.

Comment: The code in `savefile` and `saveaccount` are 100% identical, except for the `for` loop.

Comment: @gmiley but this is how we save file no? sorry im a beginner

Comment: @lediya: Yes, you're successfully saving a file.  But you're saving *the same **exact** file* twice.  Same data.  Same file name.

Comment: @David but how i can change that ?

Comment: @lediya: Presumably in one of those methods you meant to save data from `cuslist` instead of `acclist`.  In that method, change `acclist` to `cuslist`.  Additionally, in order to use a different file name, give the file a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in your "save" functions.

Here is what you have:

```
public void savefile()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("account.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cuslist.Count; i++)
        {
            var info = new List<string>
            {
                acclist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                acclist[i].PIN,
                acclist[i].accountnumber,
                acclist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
            };
            var account = String.Join(";", info);
            writer.WriteLine(account);
        }
    }
}

public void saveaccount()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("account.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
        {
            var info = new List<string>
            {
                acclist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                acclist[i].PIN,
                acclist[i].accountnumber,
                acclist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
            };
            var account = String.Join(";", info);
            writer.WriteLine(account);
        }
    }
}
```

If you look, the only difference is the `for` loops. You need to also update the inner portion to read from the correct collection, and also write to the correct output file.

Try the following:

```
public void savefile()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("customer.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cuslist.Count; i++)
        {
            var info = new List<string>
            {
                cuslist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                cuslist[i].PIN,
                cuslist[i].accountnumber,
                cuslist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
            };
            var customer = String.Join(";", info);
            writer.WriteLine(customer);
        }
    }
}

public void saveaccount()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("account.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < acclist.Count; i++)
        {
            var info = new List<string>
            {
                acclist[i].accounttype.ToString(),
                acclist[i].PIN,
                acclist[i].accountnumber,
                acclist[i].accountbalance.ToString()
            };
            var account = String.Join(";", info);
            writer.WriteLine(account);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lots man it helps me a lot ...but it cause me another problem it keeps looping the person i entered in the file

Comment: I would open a new question on that. You would probably need to include more code, specifically where you are populating your `acclist` and `cuslist` collections.

Comment: i wanted to do that but Stack overflow says "you reach your daily limite "

Comment: @lediya: Note that you call `cuslist.add(newCus);` in a loop.  So I would expect it to add the same customer to the list multiple times.